# Setting specific values in list of list within csv file

Tags: python, list, csv

what would be the correct way to set certain values of a list of lists to 0 then writing these back to a csv file?

For example:

```
list = [[a, 1, 0] , [b, 2, 5], [c, 6, 9], ............]
```

Required output:

```
list = [[a, 0, 0] , [b, 0, 0], [c, 0, 0], ............]
```

Comment: Setting values to 0 and writing your data to csv are 2 separate problems. Please ask only 1 question at a time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: Ok my apologies, still getting used to the basics!  Won't ask anything like that again.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the trailing values with a list of zeroes:

```
list = [['a', 1, 0] , ['b', 2, 5], ['c', 6, 9]]  
final_list = [[i[0]]+[0]*len(i[1:]) for i in list]
```

Output:

```
[['a', 0, 0], ['b', 0, 0], ['c', 0, 0]]
```